# How to create reproducible RandomForestClassifier in Python using jobs=-1?

Tags: python, multithreading, random-forest, random-seed

I've read at https://towardsdatascience.com/random-seeds-and-reproducibility-933da79446e3 to create reproducible machine learning models in Python, you need to set the random seed and pin the package versions.

I would like to be able to save models after training, that is, e.g. using `pickle.dump()`, load them up again and then get the same results.

At https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#notes-on-reproducibility it says:

"Sometimes it is useful to be able to reproduce the sequences given by a pseudo-random number generator. By re-using a seed value, the same sequence should be reproducible from run to run as long as multiple threads are not running."

I'm using a `RandomForestClassifier` with `jobs=-1` so I'm wondering whether I need to do more or whether this is handled internally already.

For the random seed now I have:

```py
os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = str(42)
random.seed(42)
np.random.seed(42)
```

And for the classifier I'm setting the random state:

```py
rf = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=42)
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html), you must also set the `random_state` parameter in the RandomForestClassifier:

> **random_state: int, RandomState instance or None, default=None**
>
> Controls both the randomness of the bootstrapping of the samples used when
> building trees (if bootstrap=True) and the sampling of the features to
> consider when looking for the best split at each node (if max_features
> < n_features). See [Glossary](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/glossary.html#term-random_state) for details.

For example:

```py
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
SEED = 42

clf = RandomForestClassifier(random_state = SEED)
```

---

##### CLARIFICATIONS:

In order for the experiment to be fully reproducible, all steps in the preparation of the dataset must be checked (e.g. train and test splits) even with fixed seed. `np.random.seed` does not guarantee a fixed random state for sklearn. We need to set `random_state` parameter corresponding **to each sklearn function to ensure repeatability**.

It is also sufficient to set the `random_state` in multithreading. Make sure you use the latest version of sklearn if possible to avoid possible bugs on earlier versions.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I forgot that I already had this setting as well. In answer to my original question: Does this mean the models will be reproducible (as per the quote in question)?

Comment: In order for the experiment to be fully reproducible, all steps in the preparation of the dataset must be checked (e.g. train and test splits) even with fixed seed. `np.random.seed` does not guarantee a fixed random state for sklearn. We need to set `random_state` parameter corresponding **to each sklearn function** to ensure repeatability.

Comment: OK, I have that (in train_test_split and in the classifier). So nothing else needs to be set (i.e. the notes say as long as multiple threads are not running - could you please tell me if I need to do something specific because of the jobs=-1?).

Comment: It is also sufficient to set the random_state in multithreading. Make sure you use the latest version of sklearn if possible to avoid possible bugs on earlier versions (e.g. this [issue](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/11137) on randomforestregressor)

Comment: Thank you for your fast replies!

Comment: Something is still not deterministic - reruns of the identical model configuration produce varying performance metrics.

Comment: The [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) says "to obtain a deterministic behaviour during fitting, random_state has to be fixed.". Are you sure there are no other parts in your code where there may be a need to fix random? Can you try just doing the fit N times and see that the result of the predictions is always the same?

Comment: Not sure, I'll a minimally viable example and re-add elements.